# Shell script to extract 2 values from all files?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a directory full of files like this:

```
[Location]
state=California
city=Palo Alto

[Outlet]
id=23
manager=John Doe
```

I want to write a small script, that outputs one line for each file like this:

```
John Doe,Palo Alto
```

How do I do that? I suspect some grep and looping. So far I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Manager,City > result.txt
for f in *.config
do
  cat "$f" | grep manager= >> result.txt
  cat "$f" | grep city= >> result.txt
done
```

but that's of course incomplete since grep returns the whole line on its own line and I only want the part after the first = sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo Manager,City > result.txt

for f in *.config; do
    manager=$(awk -F= '$1=="manager" {print $2}' "$f")
    city=$(   awk -F= '$1=="city"    {print $2}' "$f")

    echo "$manager,$city"
done >> result.txt
```

`awk -F=` uses an equal sign as the field separator, and then checks for the desired variables (`$1`) and prints their values (`$2`). `$(cmd)` captures the output of a command and yields strings that can be assigned to the two variables `$manager` and `$city`.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to [John Kugelman's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17561232/970195) answer but using `grep`.

```
echo Manager,City > result.txt
for file in *.config; do 
    name=$(grep -oP '(?<=manager\=).*' "$file")
    location=$(grep -oP '(?<=city\=).*' "$file")
    echo "$name,$location"
done >> result.txt
```

Comment: @stwissel You did select the answer this one was inspired from! So all is good! ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a single `awk` command, as per the following transcript:

```
pax> cat 1.config
[Location]
state=California
city=Palo Alto

[Outlet]
id=23
manager=John Doe

pax> cat 2.config
[Location]
state=Western Australia
city=Perth

[Outlet]
id=24
manager=Pax Diablo

pax> awk '
     /^city=/   {gsub (/^city=/, "", $0); city=$0}
     /^manager=/{gsub(/^manager=/, "", $0); print $0 "," city}
' *.config
John Doe,Palo Alto
Pax Diablo,Perth
```

Note that this assumes the city comes before the manager, and that all files have both city and manager. If those assumptions are incorrect, the `awk` script becomes a little more complex but it's still doable.

In that case, it becomes something like:

```
awk '
    FNR==1       {city = ""; mgr = ""}
    /^city=/     {gsub (/^city=/, "", $0); city = $0}
    /^manager=/  {gsub (/^manager=/, "", $0); mgr = $0}
                 {if (city!="" && mgr!=""){
                     print mgr "," city; city = ""; mgr = "";
                 }}
' *.config
```

What this does is to make the order irrelevant. It resets the city and manager variables to empty string at the start of each file and just stores them in the cases where it finds the relevant lines. After every line, if both are set, it prints and clears them.